# Sending an object through a socket in grails using console Web GUI

Tags: java, sockets, grails

I have two application servers in two Hosts. Each host has a Local address IP (172.x.x.x)

I want to send an object from 172.x.x.x:8080 to 172.y.y.y:8080  using Java sockets

**Server Side(172.x.x.x:8080)**

```
         def myObject="Mar7ben bil World"
         ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(8080);
         Socket socket = ss.accept();
         ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()); 
         out.writeObject(myObject);
         out.close();
```

**Client Side(172.y.y.y:8080 )**

```
Socket socket = new Socket('172.x.x.x',8080);
ObjectInputStream inp = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
Object o = inp.readObject();
obj= o;
inp.close();
socket.close();
```

i get the following error message when i run code of `server side` on console : 
http://172.x.x.x:8080/myApp/console

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:383)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:328)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:194)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:106)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Grails app listen 8080 port (http://172.x.x.x:8080/myApp/console). You have to change *Server Side* port to something else, 8081 for example.

P.S. `808x` ports are usually used for HTTP services. If you aren't making a HTTP server, it's better to chose another port. See list of well-known ports: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers#Well-known_ports